# python regex match and replace beginning and end of string but keep the middle

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe with holiday names. I have a problem that on some days, holidays are observed on different days, sometimes on the day of another holiday. Here are some example problems:

```
1  "Independence Day (Observed)"
2  "Christmas Eve, Christmas Day (Observed)"
3  "New Year's Eve, New Year's Day (Observed)"
4  "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day"
```

I want to replace all ' (Observed)' with '' and everything before a comma only if ' (Observed)' is matched. Output should be:

```
1  "Independence Day"
2  "Christmas Day"
3  "New Year's Day"
4  "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day"
```

I was able to do both independently:

```
(foo['holiday']
 .replace(to_replace=' \(Observed\)', value='', regex=True)
 .replace(to_replace='.+, ', value='', regex=True))
```

but that caused a problem with 'Martin Luther King, Jr. Day'.

Comment: Is `(Observed)` always at the end of the string?

Comment: Yes it is. Got an answer below from Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### replace.py

```
import re

input = [
    "Independence Day (Observed)",
    "Christmas Eve, Christmas Day (Observed)",
    "New Year's Eve, New Year's Day (Observed)",
    "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day"
]

for holiday in input:
    print re.sub('^(.*?, )?(.*?)( \(Observed\))$', '\\2', holiday)
```

### Output

```
> python replace.py 
Independence Day
Christmas Day
New Year's Day
Martin Luther King, Jr. Day
```

### Explanation

- `^`: Match at start of string.
- `(.*?, )?`: Match anything followed by a command and a space.  Make it a lazy match, so it doesn't consume the portion of the string we want to keep.  The last `?` makes the whole thing optional, because some of the sample input doesn't have a comma at all.
- `(.*?)`: Grab the part we want for later use in a capturing group.  This part is also a lazy match because...
- `( \(Observed\))`: Some strings might have " (Observed)" on the end, so we declare that in a separate group here.  The lazy match in the prior piece won't consume this.
- `$`: Match at end of string.

Comment: You said you had a `DataFrame`, but this results in a Python `list` instead of staying with a Pandas `DataFrame`. You lose the indices and the name this way.

Comment: Thanks! For reference, here is my final code to apply the replace to my dataframe column: `foo['holiday'].replace(to_replace='^(.*?, )?(.*?)( \(Observed\))$', value=r'\2', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
r'^(?:.*,\s*)?\b([^,]+)\s+\(Observed\).*'
```

Replace with `r'\1'` backreference.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8xd3b/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*,\s*)?` -  an optional sequence of:

  - `.*,` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of `,` on the line and then the `,`
  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([^,]+)` - 1 or more chars other than `,`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\(Observed\)` - a literal substring `(Observed)`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the line end.